# How do I implement a chromeless window with WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I want to show a chromeless modal window with a close button in the upper right corner.
Is this possible?

Comment: The WPF SDK Team posted a *excellent* article about chromeless windows available here:
*http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx* This is a *must* read!!! ![Alt text](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PzUuC.png) I also found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2010/05/10/wpf-shell-integration-library.aspx) by Lester Lebo on how to use the WPF Shell Integration Library for a custom window chrome.

Comment: @rudigrobler: What was the title for the first one? "Custom window chrome in WPF"? Now the link redirects to [Windows Presentation Foundation User Education](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wpfsdk/). Can you recover it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You'll pretty much have to roll your own Close button, but you can hide the window chrome completely using the WindowStyle attribute, like this:

```
<Window WindowStyle="None">
```

That will still have a resize border. If you want to make the window non-resizable then add ResizeMode="NoResize" to the declaration.

Answer (score 16):

Check out this blog post on [kirupa](http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/custom_wpf_windows.htm).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" >Close</Button>
</Window>
```