# Creating your own component in vb.net 2008

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls

How do you create your own custom component for vb.net 2008? I want it to simply output to a .dll, not a whole winforms app.

So, here is what I have done so far:

1. Made a class library project
2. Added a custom control object
3. Confused myself badly
4. Googled it, to no avail

How can I control the component? For example, I want my component to not have a visible design view, I want it to stay below like the stopwatch component and the notifyicon component and such, it is not something to be designed. Then, how do I edit the possible properties a user can control, and make them effect the end result? What do I place the code which powers the component on? The class library file, or something else?

Thanks for your help! I have a whole set of components I am going to create, this will get me going much faster than trial and error.

Comment: Whats wrong with the components that are already available with .NET?

Comment: Can you post a small example of the class library?

Comment: I want to make my own? There are some things those cannot do, and this way when I am done, I will not need to copy and paste code over if I want to use it, i will simply need to drag and drop.

Comment: The class lib, is, at this moment, blank, as I have no idea what the heck to do to even start making my component D:

Comment: Then how do you know you need it?

Comment: BTW... there are a bunch on Google. http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_en-USUS291US311&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=making+custom+control+in+.net

Comment: I would know what to do if I could turn a chromeless winform into a component....and I plan on re-using the same functionality over and over in all my projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may want to check some walkthrough on how to create components. Such as this one: [Walkthrough: Authoring a Component with Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151w6x12.aspx). Once you are done with that one, [there are more walkthroughs on various related topics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz2e66xh.aspx), such as how to use design-time support, implementing designers and so on.

Comment: Believe me, the difference between VB2005 and VB2008 is really not that big.

Comment: ...anyway, updated the links to point to the VB2008 versions of the articles.

Comment: Public Sub New() is the default constructor. Its always there unless you declare other constructors.

Answer (score 0):

OK... This is a really abbreviated example. You should start by basing yous off of an existing .net component.

```
Public Class MyControl
 Inherits DataGridView

'...add your properties/functionality...'

End Class
```

Then compile the DLL, and add it as a reference to whatever project you are working on. Once added, you can add the controls in the DLL into your toolbox.

[This](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/03/18/customcontrols.html) has more instructions on how to modify a UserControl (slightly different from the one above, but it explains well. [This](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_user_controls.html) is a general explanation.

@comments - 
[Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830/how-do-i-implement-a-chromeless-window-with-wpf), [there](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/68d8990a-5414-44e8-94e6-70554fa7391b), [are](http://www.google.com/search?q=chromeless+winform+.net) things that will do what you want. Start with a class that inherits Form instead of DataGridView in the example I gave you, and the changes described in the links provided.

"Your properties and functionality" is whatever you want to do that the base control does not do.

Comment: Any way to start from scratch? I *really* do not want to copy any functionality from any of them, as mine is nothing like those D:

Comment: Start small, understand how it works. Then take on the larger pieces. I find it very doubtful that there is not a control already available that doesnt serve part of your needs.

Comment: Actually, trust me, there isn't. At all..... Anyway, how do I "add my properties/functionality"? By properties, do you mean subs and functions? Can you give a better example?