# Design GUI like MS Office Applications

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio

I would like to create a windows application (not windows store app), with a GUI as elegant as [Office 360](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/) or [Github](http://windows.github.com/) for windows. It's a little hard to come up with that design if you use the normal Windows Applications in Visual Studio. Any Guidelines on how I can do that?

Comment: Draw the windows yourself?

Comment: @Voidpaw is that what they did in Microsoft or Guthub to do that?

Comment: I have no clue how they did it, as I haven't seen them share it anywhere. I would assume though that if they used their own Windows Applications, they would have reskinning going on everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two things 1) Chromeless application and 2) Professional design and layout. For the first one check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830/how-do-i-implement-a-chromeless-window-with-wpf), here is [nice example](http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/custom_wpf_windows.htm). Well regarding second part - try to recreate some existing app that you like for the beginning.

You should really use WPF, with Winforms it will require immense effort.

Comment: Yes I think it will be to great benefit if I learn WPF. But could you a bit more specific on Chromeless? Can we create applications with it, too?

Comment: @Pedram did you even open the links? There is step by step instruction how to create chromeless app and custom window. Rest is purely design.

Answer (score 1):

You really can't do that easily with WinForms. WinForms was not designed for this kind of customization of UI in mind. Yeah, there exists ways to do it and some 3rd party frameworks do have ability to draw custom UI like that, but they are usually limited to image-based skins.

Your best bet would be to learn WPF. WPF is actually meant to create these kind of UIs and in many cases, it allows you to create them quite easily.